# Show more notifications on lock screen?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s7

Like seriously, how can I show more than 5 notifications, I've enabled the setting to show more, but still, I have like 20 notifications an hour, I'm missing lots.. I want to show it until my lock screen is filled, its stupid not to.